# Monitor How Often Assemblies Are Loaded From GAC

Tags: .net, logging, monitoring, gac, diagnostics

I currently have 3 servers each running different applications.  Occasionally through installation misconfiguration and code re-factoring these machines are left with assemblies in the GAC that are no longer being referenced or used by anything.

Are there any tools anybody is aware of to monitor / log how often, or when certain assemblies are loaded from the GAC?  So after monitoring our servers for a certain amount of time I can feel confident about cleaning up the cruft.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only tool I've heard of that can do this sort of task is [Fusion Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx).